# Generate Executable Jar file in LIBGDX

Tags: java, jar, libgdx

To be clear, i know there is a thread like this on stackoverflow and he uses eclipse while I use Intellij. Creating an executable jar in eclipse and intellij are different. So before downvote kindly consider my scenario. I created a simple java game using libgdx and want to export it in an executable jar. But before doing so, I experimented in creating a jar of the one in the tutorial video of official LIBGDX.This is the jar file Dload it [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?sc80op66ddpcmd6).. If you execute it opens then close again. But when i ran the project in intellij it runs without error.

This is the image i was expecting if i execute the jar file i created..  [image]

What is wrong when i tried to create a jar file?? Anyone?? Thanks

Comment: Can you execute it at a command line and see what errors are being printed?  Its probably a ClassNotFound exception, but its hard to say.  Which platform are you on (Windows/Linux/Mac)?  You can also inspect a .jar file to see if it has what you expect (you can use 7-zip or other archive viewers).

Comment: i use windows 8 os. I run it and still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just open your exported jar file like a zip archive and export your assets folder and libraries beside your jar file then test it again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not working.. I tried to copy paste assets and libraries and put it beside the jar file..